# Failed doing npm install showing error "Undefined variable standalone_static_library in binding.gyp" and node-sass chokidar error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, npm, package

I'm updating a 3 years ago ruby on rails and react project trying to npm install but im stuck here getting this error

$ npm install

```
gyp: Undefined variable standalone_static_library in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
```

$ npm start

```
sh: node-sass-chokidar: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 build-css: `node-sass-chokidar src/styles -o src/styles`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 build-css script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried removing node_modules, update node version and npm version.

Comment: `node-sass` is [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass). `node-sass-chokidar` is also [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-chokidar).

Comment: oh yeah. I already switch to sass. thanks!

Comment: This ended up fixing it for me. Along with some simple project cleanup `npm dedupe`, `npm outdated`, and a fresh install.

Comment: Hi, @StefanoRueda I am facing the same error. Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me this issue happened with NodeJS 19 (specifically 19.2.0)

The **issue is fixed when I reverted to NodeJS 18**; aka NodeJS LTS

NodeJS LTS = Long Term Support; "recommended for most users". At the time I wrote this answer (12/9/2022), Node Long Term Support (LTS) is **NodeJS version 18.12.1**

It seems like [this issue](https://github.com/nwjs/nw-gyp/issues/155) (`Undefined variable standalone_static_library...`) may happen because:

> node 19.0.0 has been changed to make process.config read only [#43627](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/43627)

After reverting, it may still be mentioned as a warning, but not an error:

> npm ERR! (node:7120) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.

And while we're talking about versions, be careful about Python3 vs Python2!

> npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2